# Email submission in my app unable to contact server, advice?

Tags: ios, ios9

The first time you start the app I am working on, it asks if you would like to enter your email. It has worked fine up until a little bit after iOS9 and Xcode 7 (that's when we found out it wasn't working anymore). The weird thing is... Email submission is working fine on the app thats live right now, but on test flight, simulator, and the new version that's up for review it says it is unable to connect to the server when you try to submit your email. The error message that prints to the console is:

```
2015-10-20 11:35:50.011 ACT TestBank InApp[987:38253] emailPostURL: http://www.allenprep.com/tbupdate/emails.php?email=test@gmail.com&exam=ACT&needcode=0
2015-10-20 11:35:50.024 ACT TestBank InApp[987:38469] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
2015-10-20 11:35:50.026 ACT TestBank InApp[987:38253] Failed connection
```

I even reverted back to an old copy of the project from a few months back and It still is unable to connect when I submit an email, like I said I haven't touched any of the code pertaining to this... just stopped working.

[image]

Comment: Read the error and do some searching on the error. This has been covered many many times since iOS 9 came out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://)

iOS 9 has introduced a new security feature which throws an error if you do not secure the message send of your app using HTTPS, do you have any warning or errors, and are you sending the information securely? It sounds like this is the cause of your issue, same thing happened to me.

To get around this add the domain to your plist file. Open it as source code, then right click and add:

```
key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>yourserver.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Or you can turn it off all together:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: So should I just change HTTP to HTTPS in the url?

Comment: @MrDevRI I've updated my answer. Following it should solve it for you! :)